# What's the difference between ngModel.$modelValue and ngModel.$viewValue

Tags: angularjs

I have the following ckEditor directive. At the bottom are two variations that I have seen from examples on how to set the data in the editor:

```
app.directive('ckEditor', [function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {

            var ck = null;
            var config = attr.editorSize;
            if (config == 'wide') {
                ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0], { customConfig: 'config-wide.js' });
            } else {
                ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0], { customConfig: 'config-narrow.js' });
            }


            function updateModel() {
                $scope.$apply(function () {
                    ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
                });
            }

            $scope.$on('modalObjectSet', function (e, modalData) {
                // force a call to render
                ngModel.$render();
            });

            ck.on('change', updateModel);
            ck.on('mode', updateModel);
            ck.on('key', updateModel);
            ck.on('dataReady', updateModel);

            ck.on('instanceReady', function () {
                ngModel.$render();
            });

            ck.on('insertElement', function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $scope.$apply(function () {
                        ngModel.$setViewValue(ck.getData());
                    });
                }, 1000);
            });

            ngModel.$render = function (value) {
                ck.setData(ngModel.$modelValue);
            };

            ngModel.$render = function (value) {
                ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
            };
        }
    };
}])
```

Can someone tell me what is the difference between:

```
ck.setData(ngModel.$modelValue);
ck.setData(ngModel.$viewValue);
```

And which should I use. I looked at the angular documentation and it says:

```
$viewValue

Actual string value in the view.

$modelValue

The value in the model, that the control is bound to.
```

I have no idea what the author meant when he wrote this in the document :-(

Answer (score 154, accepted):

You are looking at the correct documentation, but it might just be that you're a little confused.  The `$modelValue` and `$viewValue` have one distinct difference.  It is this:

As you already noted above:

> `$viewValue:` Actual string *(or Object)* value in the view.
>   `$modelValue:` The value in the model, that the control is bound to.

I'm going to assume that your ngModel is referring to an `<input />` element...?  So your `<input>` has a string value that it displays to the user, right?  But the actual model might be some other version of that string.  For example, the input might be showing the string `'200'` but the `<input type="number">` (for example) will actually contain a model value of `200` as an integer.  So the string representation that you "view" in the `<input>` is the `ngModel.$viewValue` and the numeric representation will be the `ngModel.$modelValue`.

Another example would be a `<input type="date">` where the `$viewValue` would be something like `Jan 01, 2000` and the `$modelValue` would be an actual javascript `Date` object that represents that date string.  Does that make sense?

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: So basically, `$viewValue` is always a string?

Comment: As the docs say: `$viewValue: Actual string value in the view.`.  So, yes.

Comment: Another note. When an `<input type="text">` value is empty, the `$modelValue` property is `undefined`, whereas the `$viewValue` is `''` empty string. This can make a difference if you're sniffing the "length" of the `$modelValue` which won't work, but `$viewValue` will.

Comment: You clean my doubts, In my case date types $modelValue is what I need. Thanks

Comment: The `$viewValue` is not always a string. It is a string for the current Angular core directives, but it may be a primitive or an Object in your custom controls. A good example, is the `<input file="type">` component, where viewValue contains `FileList` object with files attached by the user. The Angular docs are confusing about this right now and should be updated.

Comment: Also not if the input is invalid the $modelValue won't be set.  Ie, if you have <input ng-minlength="8"... > and you input is only 5 characters long, the $viewValue will show those 5 characters but $modelValue will not exist.

Comment: Hi, Is it possible to have a <input string> but the actual value is number? like viewValue = "200" and modelValue = 200

Kindly see my issue in this link and see the latest fiddle.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38165818/angularjs-formatted-number-calculation/38166477?noredirect=1#comment63822012_38166477

Comment: @tennisgent I manage to do it but the var type of the input always outputs as a string. Please see my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/aldesabido/1syh7cne/19/

Answer (score 27):

You can see things like this :

- `$modelValue` is your external API, that is to say, something exposed to your controller.
- `$viewValue` is your internal API, you should use it only internally.

When editing `$viewValue`, the render method won't be called, because it is the "rendered model". You will have to do it manually, whereas the rendering method will be called automatically upon `$modelValue` modifications.

However, the information will remain consistent, thanks to `$formatters` and `$parsers` :

- If you change `$viewValue`, `$parsers` will translate it back to
  `$modelValue`.
- If you change `$modelValue`, `$formatters` will
  convert it to `$viewValue`.

Comment: When editing $viewValue, the render method won't be called.If you change $viewValue, $parsers will translate it back to $modelValue.means $modelvalue change.and rendering method will be called automatically upon $modelValue modifications.so indirectly,when $viewValue changes, render method is called. is it ?

Comment: You need to dig in into Angular ngModel two-way binding pipeline to understand how this works. When updating  `$viewValue` via `setViewValue(viewValue)` method, parsers/validators kick in (if any) and parse that `viewValue` to the modelValue, validate it, write it to the scope and then kick of `viewChangeListeners`. Next time digest runs, the model value is retrieved from the scope and compared to the $modelValue in the controller: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngModel.js#L813. If they are equal (and they will be equal in your scenario), then it returns.

Answer (score 18):

Angular has to keep track of two views of ngModel data- there's the data as seen by the DOM(browser) and then there's Angular's processed representation of those values.   The `$viewValue` is the DOM side value.  So, for example, in an `<input>` the `$viewValue` is what the user typed in to their browser.

Once someone types something in `<input>` then `$viewValue` is processed by $parsers and turned into Angular's view of the value which is called `$modelValue`.

**So you can think of `$modelValue` being angular's processed version of the value, the value you see in the model, while `$viewValue` is the raw version.**

To take this one step further imagine we do something that changes the `$modelValue`.  Angular sees this change and calls $formatters to create an updated `$viewValue` (based on the new $modelValue) to be sent to the DOM.

Comment: u mean $modelValue or $modelView ??  If $modelValue, kindly correct the typo.