# Angularjs custom directive getting viewValue as undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am a beginner in Angularjs, so please correct me if I am wrong in understanding.

Firstly, below is my code. What I am trying is to create a custom directive for input validation.

```
For example:

<input drtooltip-message type="text"  ng-minlegth="3"> //if the length of the input value is less than 3 a tooltip with custom message should be shown
<input drtooltip-message type="text"  ng-maxlegth="5">////if the length of the input value is greater than 5 a tooltip with custom message should be shown
```

**Html**

```
<div ng-app="validationApp" ng-controller="mainController">
  <input drtooltip-message type="text" name="name" class="form-control" ng-model="user.name" required  tooltip="Tooltip on left" tooltip-placement="top"  ng-minlength="5" ng-maxlength="8" >
</div>
```

**Js**

```
var validationApp = angular.module('validationApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

validationApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

});

validationApp.directive('drtooltipMessage', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<input tooltip tooltip-placement="top" >',
            replace: true,
            require: 'ngModel',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
                ctrl.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
                    alert(viewValue);//always getting 'undefined'
                }
            }
        };
});
```

I am expecting the value entered in the input box as alert value, but am getting 'undefined'.

Reference: [What's the difference between ngModel.$modelValue and ngModel.$viewValue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383812/whats-the-difference-between-ngmodel-modelvalue-and-ngmodel-viewvalue)

Answer (score 0):

Your directive template create `input type` and you are using this directive in another `input` type text. You cannot use `input` inside `input`.

The directive you created should be used in `div` or in other placeholder. as shown below. The other attribute for the directive  should be define inside the template.

```
<div drtooltip-message>
```

Comment: Please check my update in question. I am trying to use the directive as an attribute in an input field.

Answer (score 0):

You can locally get the data in your directive using `scope.ngModel` though I will give you a much better approach on implementing your solution.

Your html would probably look like this and just add your respective attributes.

```
<input type="text" your-custom-text-field ng-model="textValue" ng-tooltip-max="5">
```

Then your directive would look like this

```
validationApp.directive('yourCustomTextfield', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            template: '<input type="text" ng-model="model" ng-change="onChange()">',
            replace: true,
            require: 'ngModel',
            scope: {
                'ngToolTipMax': '=',
                'ngModel': '='
            },
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.onChange = function () {
                    // Your code goes here

                    // Update ng-model
                    scope.ngModel = scope.model;
                };   
            }
        };
});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Please check my update in question. I am trying to use the directive as an attribute in an input field.