# AngularJS formatted number calculation

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Yesterday, I am having trouble on how to make a formatted number in my number fields but now that I achieve it, I am having problem on how to do the calculation.

index.html

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input ng-model="var.value" class="integers" symbol="°" />
    <br /><br />
    {{var.value * 100}}
</div>
```

app.js

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.numeric']);

angular.module('ui.numeric', []).directive('integers', function() {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    restrict: 'EACM',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, modelCtrl) {
        scope.$watch(element, function() {
            var formatted_number = accounting.formatMoney(element.val(),"", 2,",",".","%s%v");
            modelCtrl.$setViewValue(formatted_number);
            modelCtrl.$render();
        });
        element.bind('blur', function() {

            var formatted_number = accounting.formatMoney(element.val(),"", 2,",",".","%s%v");
            modelCtrl.$setViewValue(formatted_number);
            modelCtrl.$render();
            scope.$apply();
        });
        element.bind('focus', function() {
            var plainNumber = accounting.unformat(element.val())
            if(plainNumber == "0") plainNumber = "";
            modelCtrl.$setViewValue(plainNumber);
            modelCtrl.$render();
            scope.$apply();
            console.log("I am focused!")
        });
    }
};
});

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.var = {"value":1000.36};
}
```

It works when the value of the field is less than a thousand but when I reach **1000**, the number would be formatted with comma **1,000** and it becomes string and can't do anymore calculations.

All I want is to properly format my number fields(for display) but retain the true value to do calculations without using separate variable in each number field.

Please see the fiddle. Thanks!

http://jsfiddle.net/aldesabido/1syh7cne/6/

updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/aldesabido/1syh7cne/14/

**Solution:**
changed the modelCtrl.setViewValue(number) to modelCtrl.viewValue(number) so that the display only will be affected not the actual value (not sure about this workaround though.).

http://jsfiddle.net/aldesabido/1syh7cne/18/

Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only solution I can think of is to watch for changes in `{{ var.value }}` on the controller:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.var = {"value":1000.36};

    $scope.$watch('var.value', function(val) {
        $scope.numbericVal = accounting.unformat(val);
    });
}
```

And then, use `numericVal` in your view like this: `{{numbericVal * 2}}`

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/1syh7cne/7/

---

Another RAW example that using callback function whenever the value gets changed:
http://jsfiddle.net/1syh7cne/9/

I've used the attributes to define a function that pass the object and the current numeric value. Note that you can just parse the `val` of the passed object instead of trusting the second parameter in the function.

```
var invoker = $parse(attrs.updateFunc);
invoker(scope, {number: plainNumber});
```

Just take a look - I think you'll see what I did there. But as I said - It's a general direction for a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response. But I don't really want to use two seperate variable for displaying and calculation. I hope that there's still a way for this.

Comment: I did my best, couldn't think of anything else. Hope you'll find a solution using one variable (That would be an interesting one)

Comment: Thanks for the effort bro. It would really a pain in the ass to do this in all of my number fields.

Comment: @aldesabido I have just posted another example, so take a look and let me know. I'm off to bed....

Comment: @aldesabido Thanks for that. I prepared a last example that demonstrate why the solution in your answer is not perfect - http://jsfiddle.net/1syh7cne/16/ Just by injecting `$interval` to the controller and putting some mock action (`console.log(....)`) causing Angular to trigger a digest cycle and update the view. So removing the `$apply()` is just delaying the next digest cycle - giving you a **false** feeling that everything is working fine

Comment: oh I see it now.  need more testing then. I hope that you could help me again bro.

Comment: Can't really understand what's the $digest error is.

Comment: Where exactly you see a `$digest` error? I don't see any in mine (http://jsfiddle.net/1syh7cne/9/). Can you elaborate please?

Comment: This is working great! I'll have a deeper look to see what you did, because I find it interesting. Thanks

Comment: BTW - There's also this module for input masking http://assisrafael.github.io/angular-input-masks/ (Although it looks like you managed to debug your directive and it's working just fine)

Comment: I tried that before but I think it doesn't fit on my specific need. Thanks for everythin @Alon.

Comment: Is it okay if I add you on my contact list?

Comment: I discovered another problem with my solution. It won't work if I use "+" instead it will concatenate two numbers(treat as string)

Comment: What you can do is `{{ firstStringNum * 1 + secondStringNum * 1 }}` - It usually works for me

Comment: haha. yah that would work but I really don't want to do it in all of my module. but gonna use it as my trump card.

Comment: no choice left. need to parseFloat all of it before calculation. :(

Comment: Can't you create a custom filter for that? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293769/how-to-parseint-in-angular-js)

Comment: Some of my calculations are not in the template that's why I can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not limited to using only Angular you can check out [accounting.js](http://openexchangerates.github.io/accounting.js/) library which does exactly what you need.

Then you could also keep a variable on $scope, that you use for calculation only, and you maintain the state between your var.value and that other $scope variable with help of accounting.js for formatting.

I hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: actually I am using accounting.js for my formatting. I don't really want to use two seperate variables for the formatted one and the original value.