# Difference between on-change and ng-change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, events, data-binding, angularjs-directive

Below is a pretty straightforward setup for a form drop down list. However, the `on-change` event refuses to fire... unless it's changed to `ng-change`.

This had me stuck for about an hour, since we use the same setup elsewhere in our site (i.e. model property/list/`on-change` directive) without fail.

I'm wondering what the difference is between `on-change` and `ng-change` and why one works in this instance and the other doesn't?

**View**

```
<select id="grArchive"
        name="grArchive"
        class="form-control"
        options="userList"
        ng-model="selectedUser"
        ng-options="user as user.name for user in userList"
        on-change="showSelected()">
</select>
```

**Controller**

```
scope.selectedUser = {};
scope.userList = [];

scope.showSelected = function(){
    scope.columns = addColumns;
};

var loadUserList = function(data){
    scope.userList = $.map(data, function(item){
            return {id: item.id, name: item.firstName + ' ' + item.lastName};
        });
}
```

Just in case: the user drop down populates as expected (screen shot below)

[image]

Answer (score 7):

### ng-change

`ng-change` is a directive provided by Angular core API which internally registers an expression to be called when any change happens in `$viewValue` of `ng-model` variable ([here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/a4e60cb6970d8b6fa9e0af4b9f881ee3ba7fdc99/src/ng/directive/ngChange.js#L74) is the code); assign it an expression such as `myFunction()`. That provided expression will evaluate inside the underlying controller scope. After calling an expression it runs a digest cycle to make sure bindings are updated on the view. Besides `ng-change` there are other directives used for events, like `ng-focus`,`ng-mousedown`,`ng-submit`, `ng-blur`, etc. [**Here**](http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_events.asp) is a list of such directives

### on-change

It is a way of calling a JavaScript function on `change` of input element value. It will search for the `function` which is globally available in context (obviously it will not call the function registered in angular controller) and evaluate it.

Comment: Is funny how people say 'old way'. Which is the new way then?

Comment: @Misters Oh, my bad, I didn't added it intentionally, I remove `old` word. :(

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/a4e60cb6970d8b6fa9e0af4b9f881ee3ba7fdc99/src/ng/directive/ngChange.js it does not bind any event itself

Comment: @PetrAveryanov You are partially correct, Thanks for heads up. Actually other events are handled in that way I talked, [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/a4e60cb6970d8b6fa9e0af4b9f881ee3ba7fdc99/src/ng/directive/ngEventDirs.js#L49) you can see.

Comment: The thing I said partial because, If you look at how `$viewChangeListner` call the registered listner, then you will understand indirectly it does call the register listener on `change` event.   Basically there in one `input` change event, which does call, $setViewValue method to update `$viewValue`, which call one method to set `$viewValue` to `$modelValue`, between that it called `$commitValue` method to make changes in `$modelValue` in that method only it call listeners of `$viewChangeListner`.

Comment: I'm still not getting the specifics of what makes them different. Does `on-change` listens for a change in the HTML input element, but doesn't ng-change do the same, by proxy, by listening for a change in the model property via the HTML input element?

Comment: @NealR `ng-change` does get fired when underlying `ng-model` value gets changed. Behind the scene angular maintain two value for each value those are [`$viewValue` & `$modelValue`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19383812/whats-the-difference-between-ngmodel-modelvalue-and-ngmodel-viewvalue), so when `$modelValue` gets change only that time it fires change event by [this line](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/a4e60cb6970d8b6fa9e0af4b9f881ee3ba7fdc99/src/ng/directive/ngChange.js#L75)